# How to create mysql function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, mysql-function

i have the following sql query

```
SELECT id,
  title,
  total_likes, 
  IFNULL(SELECT 1 FROM 'likedata' WHERE user_id=$UID AND post_id=posts.id)0) AS is_liked 
FROM 'posts'
```

I want to create mysql function to make my query bit shorter,

i don't know how to wrap the second query into **sql function** and pass 2 variables ($UID and $PID) to function to make this query shorter and more understandable.

any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: Why is 'Table1' a string? Likewise for 'table2'?

Comment: sorry, it meant to be table name, i'm pretty new to sql, please pardon me

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you just posted your actual query

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good use case for a function.

A more fluent way of expressing this in SQL would be to use a left outer join, e.g:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, posts.total_likes,
  (likedata.id IS NOT NULL) AS is_liked
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN likedata ON (
  posts.id = likedata.post_id AND likedata.user_id = $UID
)
```

[You can see this in action here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91040/5)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what if i have multiple data and table, in that case the query will become very long, i want to enclose it in function to make it more manageable.

Comment: @PurgeProject Then you grit your teeth and write a long query. Again: this isn't a good use case for functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually simply use `exists`.  MySQL treats booleans as numbers, so:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.total_likes, 
       ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM likedata ld WHERE ld.post_id = p.id AND ld.user_id = $UID)
       ) as is_liked 
FROM posts p;
```

This seems closest to your original intent.

@duskwuff's answer is also a typical way to approach this.  There is a slight different, because duplicates in `likedata` would result in duplicate rows in the result set using a `join`.

For either form, you want an index on `likedata(post_id, user_id)`.  And if you are passing `$UID` in, you should be using parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but i want to do this with functions because i know in future i need to change the query, so with mysql function it will lot easier to do. Can you please provide help with FUNCTION?